# Upload shell script files and dependent json files to nexus repository

Tags: shell-scripting

I have a bunch of shell scripts that perform certain validation on the application code. As these scripts are packaged with the code due, the developers can alter the checks and get their code passed but we don't want it to happen.

So we thought of uploading all shell scripts to nexus repository and download them as a dependent library through gradle.

I am looking for help in uploading the shell scripts to nexus, I have gone through many links available in Google but all of them are for uploading Java files to nexus but nothing on non-java files.

Can someone please let me know how can we upload these shell scripts to nexus and also download and refer them in the actual application code.